# DLL load failed for all packages after 'conda update' command

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

So I recently updated all of my packages that were installed via Anaconda via the usual command:

```
conda update
```

Unfortunately, none of the Python modules I had install will import correctly. Every single one raises:

> ImportError:DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

With the following traceback:
[image]

Running `conda info` I see that the root environment, deafult environment are indeed the directory that Anaconda was installed in.
[image]

The whole issue arose when trying to update `scipy` via `pip`; because the module was download with anaconda it should be updated via the conda update command. However, I tried with `pip` first ('basically as a reflex') and it returned the error. Unforunately, I didnt save a screenshot of the traceback because I thought it would be straightforward to just run `conda` after receiving the error. Unfortunately, it isn't or I am just missing something.

Comment: SOLVED: The issue was the newly updated packages had some extra dependencies that were added in newer versions of anaconda. After updating conda and then anaconda everything runs nominally